# I feel confused about define-macro in scheme

Tags: scheme, lisp

What's the difference between the two define-macro below?

```
(define-macro (f x) (+ x 2))
(define-macro (g x) (list '+ x 2))
```

when I compute (f (+ 2 3)), there is an error, but the second one works well. Why?

Comment: compile how? what error? include full error message please.

Comment: `define-macro` is not part of Scheme as far as I know: you should specify which implementation you are using.

Answer (score 2):

Macros transform code to new code. It does this as early as possible. Eg. if you use a macro in a function it usually gets expanded when that function is created, long before the code is executed.

`(f (+ 2 3))` will apply the macro function `f` with the value `'(+ 2 3)` as `x`. It will try to `(+ '(+ 2 3) 2)` of which the result is the new code that replaces the whole `(f (+ 2 3))` entirely. However `+` cannot add a list to a number so it makes no sense to create a macro like that.

`(g (+ 2 3))` will apply the macro function `g` with the value `'(+ 2 3)` as `x`.
It will try to `(list '+ '(+ 2 3) 2))` of which the result is `(+ (+ 2 3) 2)`. This is then put verbatim at the code location of `(g (+ 2 3))` as if it has always been `(+ (+ 2 3) 2)` all along before the program starts executing. It works because `(+ (+ 2 3) 2)` is a valid expression.

It's important to understand that the macro does not calculate values. It takes code in one format and create new code in another. eg. we can make `let1`

```
(let1 x (+ 10 2)
  (+ x x))
```

And it should be translated to

```
(let ((x (+ 10 2)))
  (+ x x))
```

So the macro is:

```
(define-macro (let1 name expression . body)
  `(let ((,name ,expression)) ,@body))
```

NB: `define-macro` is not specified in any version of Scheme. Many sheme implementations have `defmacro` and `define-macro` implemented with slightly different syntax and specification. Code that uses `define-macro` is therefor not Scheme code, but a dialect dictated by the implementers. My code was tested in `#lang racket` with `(require compatibility/defmacro)`, but it might not work in your Scheme implementation. The only portable macro system in Scheme is `define-syntax` with `syntax-rules`.